# Правильно менять title через document.title в create-react-app приложении?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Как правильно менять title страницы в SPA приложении create-react-app? Я попробовал через простой document.title в коде, всё работает, теперь вопрос можно ли так делать и правильно ли это?

Вопрос маленький но мне очень важен ответ, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная концепция react-а, это отображение state (на странице)
Поэтому, правильно было бы менять title в state, а уж затем отображать измененное значение